# vt420 Terminal with 132 columns

Tags: terminal-emulator

I'm looking for a terminal emulator which will work properly with 132 column switching when used with vt420 escape sequences.

I have seen xterm & gnome-terminal can adjust to 132 column manually but they adjust the window size and do not listen to escape sequences.

Is there a way to get the font to adjust when switching from 80 to 132 columns in vt420 mode in any open source terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

short: no

long:

80/132-column switching is a **vt100** feature.  vt100 is a **subset** of vt420.  xterm has a workable vt420 emulation, and will **identify** as a vt420.  The other available choices neither have a workable vt420 emulation, nor do they identify themselves as such.

In xterm, the 80/132-column switching feature is optional, controlled by the [**c132**](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:c132) resource because some users decided it is a nuisance (actually they phrased the criticism as a "security problem").  vte (the emulator under the *skin* "gnome-terminal") and other terminals such as KDE konsole do not make that distinction.

KDE konsole probably could be modified to do this; unlike the other terminals its developers have chosen to scale fonts in preference to changing the window size.  But it's not a currently implemented feature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently we are using PowerTerm (it's proprietary and expensive). It would be good to find a solution which is open source and doesn't cost as much.